# Anaconda spyder menus are not working and minimize maximize close icons disappeared

Tags: anaconda, spyder

When I am clicking on File, Edit, Search ect. the background of the text turns blue, so it recognizes the click, but the menu does not show up. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.And also maximize minimize close buttons disappeared.plus right click also not working.

I have updated the conda. Still same issue is there.
Commands that I have used are:

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda update spyder
```

Comment: What version of Spyder are you running? Can you tell?

Comment: version is 3.2.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure but try <kbd>F11</kbd>. If you spyder has gone to full-screen mode, to exit full-screen mode press <kbd>F11</kbd>. Hope this helps you but not sure.